# How can I access a Django model field via a backward relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've three Django models `ModelA`, `ModelB` and `ModelC`. In my logic either an instance of `ModelB` or `ModelC` is associated with `ModelA` via a OneToOne relationship. I'd like to access the field `of_interest` via `ModelA`s backwards relationship to `ModelB` or `ModelC`. Is this possible?

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    ...

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.OneToOneField(
        ModelA,
        related_name='%(class)s_model_a',
        of_interest=models.IntegerField(default=42),
        ...
    )

class ModelC(models.Model):
    model_a = models.OneToOneField(
        ModelC,
        related_name='%(class)s_model_a',
        of_interest=models.IntegerField(default=42),
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Maybe you add some example data and show the desired behaviour. It is unclear to me what you mean by `access`. ALso whic of the involved models has the field `of_interest`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a OneToOneField, but that is probably a typo.

But if you have model A, then automatically the model B and C are retrievable by using `model_a.modelb`, or `model_a.modelc`. In your case it would be `model_a.modelb_model_a` and `model_a.modelc_model_a`, because you set a related name.

But using this attrs could lead to an Error, if an object doesn't exist yet for model B or C, thus you'll be missing a reference. In this case you could work with hasattr. Thus `hasattr(model_a, 'modelb_model_a')`.

```
model_a = ModelA.objects.get()
of_interest = hasattr(model_a, 'modelb_model_a') and model_a.modelb_model_a.of_interest'
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed the typo. Thx. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I have to adjust the code snippet cause of my custom `related_names` I guess.

Comment: Yeah, if you still have problem, you should edit your question. But there is more not clear,  as mentioned in the other comment, what is of_interest. Is it a separate field on Model B and C? Cause now its an argument for the OneToOneField.

Comment: The field type of `of_interest` should not make any difference. Anyway... I adjusted the question.

Comment: `model_a.modelb_model_a.of_interest` should be `model_a.modelbs_model_a.of_interest`?

Comment: If you really have `'%(class)s_model_a'` as related name, then that won't work. As far as I know the string won't be formatted. Thus I would remove the whole related name if I were you. Which allows `model_a.modelb.of_interest`

Comment: It is best practice to have unique related_names: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name by prefixing with `"%(app_label)s_%(class)s_..."` to prevent name clashes.

Comment: Oké, that is true. But 1. Django raises an error when there is a conflict, which will notify of you of this error. 2. Documentation says `%(class)s` only works while using it in combination with base classes (second paragraph). 3. Your models both have an unique name, which automatically gives it an unique name.

Comment: Yes, but in case you've several apps with same model names there would be a conflict. To keep this question as generic as possible I'd stick to this best practice.

Comment: True, but then you should practice it correctly, and make a base model. See the comment in the docs; _To work around this problem, when you are using related_name or related_query_name in an abstract base class (**only**), part of the value should contain '%(app_label)s' and '%(class)s'._